# Brezis' proof of Hille-Yosida theorem: how to obtain $|\frac{d u_n}{d t}(t)-\frac{d u_m}{d t}(t)| \le |A u_{0 n}-A u_{0 m}|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ together with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $|\cdot|$ be the induced norm. I'm reading *Theorem 7.4 (Hille-Yosida)* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. Then, given any $u_0 \in D(A)$ there exists a unique function
> $$
> u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))
> $$
> satisfying
> $$
> (6) \quad \begin{cases}
> \frac{d u}{d t}+A u&=0 \quad \text{on} \quad [0,+\infty), \\
> u(0)&=u_0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Moreover,
> $$
> |u(t)| \leq\left|u_0\right| \quad \text { and } \quad\left|\frac{d u}{d t}(t)\right|=|A u(t)| \leq\left|A u_0\right| \quad \forall t \geq 0.
> $$

My question is about the last step of the proof, i.e.,

> We now turn to the proof of *Theorem 7.4.* Given $u_0 \in D(A)$ we construct (using *Lemma 7.2*) a sequence $\left(u_{0 n}\right)$ in $D\left(A^2\right)$ such that $u_{0 n} \rightarrow u_0$ and $A u_{0 n} \rightarrow A u_0$. By **Step 5** we know that there is a solution $u_n$ of the problem
> $$
> (19) \quad \begin{cases}
> \frac{d u_n}{d t}+A u_n &= 0 \quad \text { on }[0,+\infty), \\
> u_n(0) &= u_{0 n} .
> \end{cases}
> $$
> We have, for all $t \geq 0$,
> $$
> (20) \quad\begin{cases}
> \left|u_n(t)-u_m(t)\right| & \leq\left|u_{0 n}-u_{0 m}\right| &\xrightarrow{m, n \rightarrow \infty} 0, \\
> \left|\frac{d u_n}{d t}(t)-\frac{d u_m}{d t}(t)\right| & \leq\left|A u_{0 n}-A u_{0 m}\right| &\xrightarrow{m, n \rightarrow \infty} 0 .
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Therefore
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> u_n(t) & \rightarrow u(t) & \text { uniformly on }[0,+\infty), \\
> \frac{d u_n}{d t}(t) & \rightarrow \frac{d u}{d t}(t) & \text { uniformly on }[0,+\infty).
> \end{align*}
> $$
> with $u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H)$. Passing to the limit in (19) - using the fact that $A$ is a closed operator-we see that $u(t) \in D(A)$ and $u$ satisfies (6). From (6) we deduce that $u \in C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))$.

Could you please explain how to obtain the inequalities in (20)?

---

**Update** I have figured how to prove the first inequality, but I'm stuck at the second one.

> We have
> $$
> \left ( \frac{d u_n}{d t}+A u_n \right ) - \left ( \frac{d u_m}{d t}+A u_m \right ) = 0,
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} |u_n -u_m|^2 &= - \langle A (u_n -  u_m), u_n-u_m \rangle \\
> & \le 0 \quad \text{because } A \text{ is monotone}.
> \end{align*}
> $$
> Then the map $t \mapsto |u_n (t) -u_m (t)|^2$ is non-increasing. Then
> $$
> \left|u_n(t)-u_m(t)\right|  \leq\left|u_{n} (0) - u_{m} (0)\right| = \left|u_{0 n}-u_{0 m}\right|.
> $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was silly. Those inequalities are actually trivial.

---

Notice that the solution of problem (19) will satisfy the upper bounds
$$
|u_n(t)| \leq\left|u_{0n}\right| \quad \text {and} \quad\left|\frac{d u_n}{d t}(t)\right|=|A u_n(t)| \leq\left|A u_{0n}\right| \quad \forall t \geq 0.
$$

The two desired inequalities then follow by noticing that if $u_n, u_m$ are solutions of (19), then so are $u_n \pm u_m$ with the corresponding initial data $u_{0n} \pm u_{0m}$.